# 'make: *** [TLS.o] Error 1' while installing nzbget

Tags: installation, compiling, install-from-source, make

I'm trying to install [nzbget](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nzbget/) on ubuntu 11.10.

Here's the output of `./configure`

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for g++... g++
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for tar... /bin/tar
checking for make... /usr/bin/make
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking sys/prctl.h usability... yes
checking sys/prctl.h presence... yes
checking for sys/prctl.h... yes
checking for library containing pthread_create... -lpthread
checking for library containing socket... none required
checking for library containing inet_addr... none required
checking for library containing hstrerror... none required
checking for getopt_long... yes
checking for stat64... yes
checking for ctime_r... yes, and it takes 2 arguments
checking for getaddrinfo... yes
checking for library containing getaddrinfo... none required
checking for type of socket length (socklen_t)... socklen_t
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for libxml2... yes
checking libxml/tree.h usability... yes
checking libxml/tree.h presence... yes
checking for libxml/tree.h... yes
checking for library containing xmlNewNode... -lxml2
checking whether to use curses... yes
checking ncurses.h usability... yes
checking ncurses.h presence... yes
checking for ncurses.h... yes
checking for library containing refresh... -lncurses
checking whether to include code for par-checking... yes
checking for libsigc... yes
checking sigc++/type_traits.h usability... yes
checking sigc++/type_traits.h presence... yes
checking for sigc++/type_traits.h... yes
checking libpar2/libpar2.h usability... yes
checking libpar2/libpar2.h presence... yes
checking for libpar2/libpar2.h... yes
checking for library containing _ZN12Par2RepairerC1Ev... -lpar2
checking for libpar2 linking... yes
checking whether libpar2 supports cancelling... no
checking whether to use TLS/SSL... yes
checking gnutls/gnutls.h usability... no
checking gnutls/gnutls.h presence... no
checking for gnutls/gnutls.h... no
checking openssl/ssl.h usability... yes
checking openssl/ssl.h presence... yes
checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for library containing SSL_library_init... -lssl
checking whether to include all debugging code... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
```

Here's the output of `make`

```
/usr/bin/make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/james/nzbget/nzbget-0.7.0'
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT ArticleDownloader.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/ArticleDownloader.Tpo" -c -o ArticleDownloader.o ArticleDownloader.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/ArticleDownloader.Tpo" ".deps/ArticleDownloader.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/ArticleDownloader.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
ArticleDownloader.cpp: In member function ‘void ArticleDownloader::CompleteFileParts()’:
ArticleDownloader.cpp:1032:160: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘std::vector<ArticleInfo*>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat]
ArticleDownloader.cpp:1032:160: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 5 has type ‘std::vector<ArticleInfo*>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat]
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT BinRpc.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/BinRpc.Tpo" -c -o BinRpc.o BinRpc.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/BinRpc.Tpo" ".deps/BinRpc.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/BinRpc.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT ColoredFrontend.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/ColoredFrontend.Tpo" -c -o ColoredFrontend.o ColoredFrontend.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/ColoredFrontend.Tpo" ".deps/ColoredFrontend.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/ColoredFrontend.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT Connection.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/Connection.Tpo" -c -o Connection.o Connection.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/Connection.Tpo" ".deps/Connection.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/Connection.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT Decoder.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/Decoder.Tpo" -c -o Decoder.o Decoder.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/Decoder.Tpo" ".deps/Decoder.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/Decoder.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT DiskState.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/DiskState.Tpo" -c -o DiskState.o DiskState.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/DiskState.Tpo" ".deps/DiskState.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/DiskState.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
DiskState.cpp: In member function ‘void DiskState::SaveNZBList(DownloadQueue*, FILE*)’:
DiskState.cpp:187:67: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘std::deque<NZBInfo*>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat]
DiskState.cpp:209:65: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘std::vector<char*>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat]
DiskState.cpp:224:61: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘std::deque<NZBParameter*>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat]
DiskState.cpp:232:45: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘std::deque<Message*>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat]
DiskState.cpp: In member function ‘void DiskState::SaveFileQueue(DownloadQueue*, FileQueue*, FILE*)’:
DiskState.cpp:384:45: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘std::deque<FileInfo*>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat]
DiskState.cpp: In member function ‘bool DiskState::SaveFileInfo(FileInfo*, const char*)’:
DiskState.cpp:470:57: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘std::vector<char*>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat]
DiskState.cpp:476:59: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘std::vector<ArticleInfo*>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat]
DiskState.cpp: In member function ‘void DiskState::SavePostQueue(DownloadQueue*, FILE*)’:
DiskState.cpp:568:65: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘std::deque<PostInfo*>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat]
DiskState.cpp: In member function ‘void DiskState::SaveHistory(DownloadQueue*, FILE*)’:
DiskState.cpp:799:67: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘std::deque<NZBInfo*>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat]
DiskState.cpp: In member function ‘bool DiskState::DiscardDownloadQueue()’:
DiskState.cpp:948:42: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char*’, but argument 4 has type ‘char (*)[100]’ [-Wformat]
DiskState.cpp:874:51: warning: ignoring return value of ‘char* fgets(char*, int, FILE*)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
DiskState.cpp:881:32: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int fscanf(FILE*, const char*, ...)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
DiskState.cpp:943:32: warning: ignoring return value of ‘int fscanf(FILE*, const char*, ...)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
DiskState.cpp: In member function ‘bool DiskState::LoadOldPostQueue(DownloadQueue*)’:
DiskState.cpp:652:51: warning: ignoring return value of ‘char* fgets(char*, int, FILE*)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
DiskState.cpp: In member function ‘bool DiskState::LoadDownloadQueue(DownloadQueue*)’:
DiskState.cpp:133:51: warning: ignoring return value of ‘char* fgets(char*, int, FILE*)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT DownloadInfo.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/DownloadInfo.Tpo" -c -o DownloadInfo.o DownloadInfo.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/DownloadInfo.Tpo" ".deps/DownloadInfo.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/DownloadInfo.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT Frontend.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/Frontend.Tpo" -c -o Frontend.o Frontend.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/Frontend.Tpo" ".deps/Frontend.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/Frontend.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT Log.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/Log.Tpo" -c -o Log.o Log.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/Log.Tpo" ".deps/Log.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/Log.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT LoggableFrontend.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/LoggableFrontend.Tpo" -c -o LoggableFrontend.o LoggableFrontend.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/LoggableFrontend.Tpo" ".deps/LoggableFrontend.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/LoggableFrontend.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT NCursesFrontend.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/NCursesFrontend.Tpo" -c -o NCursesFrontend.o NCursesFrontend.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/NCursesFrontend.Tpo" ".deps/NCursesFrontend.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/NCursesFrontend.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
NCursesFrontend.cpp: In member function ‘void NCursesFrontend::PrintFileQueue()’:
NCursesFrontend.cpp:796:82: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 5 has type ‘std::deque<FileInfo*>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat]
NCursesFrontend.cpp:796:82: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 6 has type ‘std::deque<FileInfo*>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat]
NCursesFrontend.cpp:796:82: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 5 has type ‘std::deque<FileInfo*>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat]
NCursesFrontend.cpp:796:82: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 6 has type ‘std::deque<FileInfo*>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat]
NCursesFrontend.cpp: In member function ‘void NCursesFrontend::PrintGroupQueue()’:
NCursesFrontend.cpp:965:75: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 5 has type ‘std::deque<GroupInfo*>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat]
NCursesFrontend.cpp:965:75: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 5 has type ‘std::deque<GroupInfo*>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat]
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT NNTPConnection.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/NNTPConnection.Tpo" -c -o NNTPConnection.o NNTPConnection.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/NNTPConnection.Tpo" ".deps/NNTPConnection.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/NNTPConnection.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT NZBFile.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/NZBFile.Tpo" -c -o NZBFile.o NZBFile.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/NZBFile.Tpo" ".deps/NZBFile.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/NZBFile.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT NetAddress.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/NetAddress.Tpo" -c -o NetAddress.o NetAddress.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/NetAddress.Tpo" ".deps/NetAddress.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/NetAddress.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT NewsServer.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/NewsServer.Tpo" -c -o NewsServer.o NewsServer.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/NewsServer.Tpo" ".deps/NewsServer.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/NewsServer.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT Observer.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/Observer.Tpo" -c -o Observer.o Observer.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/Observer.Tpo" ".deps/Observer.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/Observer.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT Options.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/Options.Tpo" -c -o Options.o Options.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/Options.Tpo" ".deps/Options.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/Options.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
Options.cpp: In member function ‘void Options::InitFileArg(int, char**)’:
Options.cpp:1221:36: warning: ignoring return value of ‘char* getcwd(char*, size_t)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT ParChecker.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/ParChecker.Tpo" -c -o ParChecker.o ParChecker.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/ParChecker.Tpo" ".deps/ParChecker.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/ParChecker.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT PrePostProcessor.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/PrePostProcessor.Tpo" -c -o PrePostProcessor.o PrePostProcessor.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/PrePostProcessor.Tpo" ".deps/PrePostProcessor.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/PrePostProcessor.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT QueueCoordinator.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/QueueCoordinator.Tpo" -c -o QueueCoordinator.o QueueCoordinator.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/QueueCoordinator.Tpo" ".deps/QueueCoordinator.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/QueueCoordinator.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
QueueCoordinator.cpp: In member function ‘void QueueCoordinator::BuildArticleFilename(ArticleDownloader*, FileInfo*, ArticleInfo*)’:
QueueCoordinator.cpp:489:166: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 8 has type ‘std::vector<ArticleInfo*>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat]
QueueCoordinator.cpp:489:166: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 8 has type ‘std::vector<ArticleInfo*>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat]
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT QueueEditor.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/QueueEditor.Tpo" -c -o QueueEditor.o QueueEditor.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/QueueEditor.Tpo" ".deps/QueueEditor.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/QueueEditor.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT RemoteClient.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/RemoteClient.Tpo" -c -o RemoteClient.o RemoteClient.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/RemoteClient.Tpo" ".deps/RemoteClient.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/RemoteClient.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:642:0,
                 from RemoteClient.cpp:36:
In function ‘char* strncat(char*, const char*, size_t)’,
    inlined from ‘bool RemoteClient::RequestServerList(bool, bool)’ at RemoteClient.cpp:480:59:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:152:71: warning: call to char* __builtin___strncat_chk(char*, const char*, long unsigned int, long unsigned int) might overflow destination buffer [enabled by default]
In function ‘char* strncat(char*, const char*, size_t)’,
    inlined from ‘bool RemoteClient::RequestServerList(bool, bool)’ at RemoteClient.cpp:482:60:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:152:71: warning: call to char* __builtin___strncat_chk(char*, const char*, long unsigned int, long unsigned int) might overflow destination buffer [enabled by default]
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT RemoteServer.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/RemoteServer.Tpo" -c -o RemoteServer.o RemoteServer.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/RemoteServer.Tpo" ".deps/RemoteServer.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/RemoteServer.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT Scanner.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/Scanner.Tpo" -c -o Scanner.o Scanner.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/Scanner.Tpo" ".deps/Scanner.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/Scanner.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT Scheduler.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/Scheduler.Tpo" -c -o Scheduler.o Scheduler.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/Scheduler.Tpo" ".deps/Scheduler.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/Scheduler.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT ScriptController.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/ScriptController.Tpo" -c -o ScriptController.o ScriptController.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/ScriptController.Tpo" ".deps/ScriptController.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/ScriptController.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT ServerPool.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/ServerPool.Tpo" -c -o ServerPool.o ServerPool.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/ServerPool.Tpo" ".deps/ServerPool.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/ServerPool.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT svn_version.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/svn_version.Tpo" -c -o svn_version.o svn_version.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/svn_version.Tpo" ".deps/svn_version.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/svn_version.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT TLS.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/TLS.Tpo" -c -o TLS.o TLS.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/TLS.Tpo" ".deps/TLS.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/TLS.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
TLS.cpp: In function ‘int tls_check_cert(tls_t*, const char*, int, char**)’:
TLS.cpp:911:5: error: ‘STACK’ was not declared in this scope
TLS.cpp:911:12: error: ‘subj_alt_names’ was not declared in this scope
TLS.cpp:963:10: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
TLS.cpp:963:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘X509_get_ext_d2i’
TLS.cpp:1564:1: error: expected ‘)’ at end of input
TLS.cpp:1564:1: error: expected statement at end of input
TLS.cpp:1564:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
make[1]: *** [TLS.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/james/nzbget/nzbget-0.7.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here's the output of `sudo make install`

```
if g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -I/usr/include/libxml2   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include  -g -O2 -MT TLS.o -MD -MP -MF ".deps/TLS.Tpo" -c -o TLS.o TLS.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/TLS.Tpo" ".deps/TLS.Po"; else rm -f ".deps/TLS.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
TLS.cpp: In function ‘int tls_check_cert(tls_t*, const char*, int, char**)’:
TLS.cpp:911:5: error: ‘STACK’ was not declared in this scope
TLS.cpp:911:12: error: ‘subj_alt_names’ was not declared in this scope
TLS.cpp:963:10: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
TLS.cpp:963:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘X509_get_ext_d2i’
TLS.cpp:1564:1: error: expected ‘)’ at end of input
TLS.cpp:1564:1: error: expected statement at end of input
TLS.cpp:1564:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
make: *** [TLS.o] Error 1
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: nzbget is available from the repositories, do you really need to build it from source ?

Comment: excellent! didn't know

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to build from source, better use the source from the package in the repositories:

```
cd /tmp
dget -ux http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/nzbget/nzbget_0.7.0-2.dsc
sudo apt-get build-dep nzbget
cd nzbget-0.7.0
debuild -uc -us
```